# Storage Profile error creating a VS2019 VM in Azure DevTest Lab

Tags: azure

I'm new using Azure (In fact, I'm learning currently) and I'm trying to create a VM inside a DevTest Lab using the VS 2019 Enterprise for this and every time I try to create the VM I get the following error:

> The platform image
>   'microsoftvisualstudio:visualstudio2019:vs-2019-ent-win10-n:latest' is
>   not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are
>   correct. For more details about storage profile information, please
>   refer to https://aka.ms/storageprofile

I checked this URL but this is a C# because it redirects me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.storageprofile?view=azure-dotnet

Do you have any idea about what's wrong with my profile? Is there any data I need to share here to be more clear?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be running into an issue as mentioned in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2b94914-ac48-4ba6-a941-9266455bddc5/azure-devtest-labs-platform-image-not-available-windows-10-vs2019-community?forum=AzureDevTestLabs).

You can find a solution covered by Raf Daru in their blog:

https://medium.com/@rafique82.ai/azure-virtual-machine-visual-studio-platform-image-not-found-4234fe058317

The blog says that If you read the error message carefully, you will observe that even though Visual Studio Virtual Machine Images are available out of the box, there seems to be an issue with the way the default resource deployment for Visual Studio VMs is set up and this results in deployment failing over the name of the image — `microsoftvisualstudio:visualstudio2019latest:vs-2019-comm-latest-win10-n:latest` — in this case. So in order to identify the root cause and fix this error please follow the steps mentioned in the mentioned blog.

Hope this helps!